# QLabel correct positioning for text outline

Tags: python, pyqt5, outline

I am trying to create a label with text outline. I just want a simple white text with black outline. I first tried to do it in css like this `label.setStyleSheet("color:white; outline:2px black;")`
but outline didn’t do anything.

I did lots of searching and found the way to do it with qpainter path. But the problem is that the text is always cut off. [image]

According to the function the text is supposed to be started from the bottom left but it starts too low and left. I know I can find a point by trial error so it doesn’t gets cut off- you can -20 to the height and it will be fine enough for this one. But it will only fix this specific text! It wont be the same for any label with a different size or text or font.

I will put the minimal code example here

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QMainWindow


class MainLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(MainLabel, self).__init__(text)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        font=QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(70)
        painterPath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        #how to get the right positioning for addText
        painterPath.addText(0, self.height(), font,self.text())#HERE
        qp.strokePath(painterPath, QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0,0,0), 6))
        qp.fillPath(painterPath, QtGui.QColor(255,255,255))
        qp.end()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.centralWidget=QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.lay)
        self.label = MainLabel("text gets cut off")
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font-size:70pt;color:white; outline:2px black;")
        self.lay.addWidget(self.label)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It is such a common thing that I see literally everywhere but yet there is no simple function for this in PYQT without causing more issue? So the normal Qlabel will deal with the positioning automatically, but if you want text outline you have to give that up!

**So I am asking how to find the correct positioning like a normal Qlabel if this is the only way to have text outline, otherwise if there is some other way that is better please tell me.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because there is no convenient function or stylesheet property does not mean there is no consistent solution!

There are a number of properties to consider to set the baseline position of the text: the geometry of the QLabel, boundingRect of the text, alignment, indent, font metrics. The outlined text is going to be larger overall than regular text of the same point size, so the `sizeHint` and `minimumSizeHint` are reimplemented to account for it. The docs explain how [indent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#indent-prop) is calculated and used with alignment. The text and character geometry, ascent, descent, and bearings are obtained from QFontMetrics. With this information a position for `QPainterPath.addText` can be determined that will emulate QLabel.

```
import sys, math
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
        
class OutlinedLabel(QLabel):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.w = 1 / 25
        self.mode = True
        self.setBrush(Qt.white)
        self.setPen(Qt.black)

    def scaledOutlineMode(self):
        return self.mode

    def setScaledOutlineMode(self, state):
        self.mode = state

    def outlineThickness(self):
        return self.w * self.font().pointSize() if self.mode else self.w

    def setOutlineThickness(self, value):
        self.w = value

    def setBrush(self, brush):
        if not isinstance(brush, QBrush):
            brush = QBrush(brush)
        self.brush = brush

    def setPen(self, pen):
        if not isinstance(pen, QPen):
            pen = QPen(pen)
        pen.setJoinStyle(Qt.RoundJoin)
        self.pen = pen

    def sizeHint(self):
        w = math.ceil(self.outlineThickness() * 2)
        return super().sizeHint() + QSize(w, w)
    
    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        w = math.ceil(self.outlineThickness() * 2)
        return super().minimumSizeHint() + QSize(w, w)
    
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        w = self.outlineThickness()
        rect = self.rect()
        metrics = QFontMetrics(self.font())
        tr = metrics.boundingRect(self.text()).adjusted(0, 0, w, w)
        if self.indent() == -1:
            if self.frameWidth():
                indent = (metrics.boundingRect('x').width() + w * 2) / 2
            else:
                indent = w
        else:
            indent = self.indent()

        if self.alignment() & Qt.AlignLeft:
            x = rect.left() + indent - min(metrics.leftBearing(self.text()[0]), 0)
        elif self.alignment() & Qt.AlignRight:
            x = rect.x() + rect.width() - indent - tr.width()
        else:
            x = (rect.width() - tr.width()) / 2
            
        if self.alignment() & Qt.AlignTop:
            y = rect.top() + indent + metrics.ascent()
        elif self.alignment() & Qt.AlignBottom:
            y = rect.y() + rect.height() - indent - metrics.descent()
        else:
            y = (rect.height() + metrics.ascent() - metrics.descent()) / 2

        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addText(x, y, self.font(), self.text())
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.pen.setWidthF(w * 2)
        qp.strokePath(path, self.pen)
        if 1 < self.brush.style() < 15:
            qp.fillPath(path, self.palette().window())
        qp.fillPath(path, self.brush)
```

You can set the `OutlinedLabel` fill and outline color with `setBrush` and `setPen`. The default is white text with a black outline. The outline thickness is based on the point size of the font, the default ratio is 1/25 (i.e. a 25pt font will have a 1px thick outline). Use `setOutlineThickness` to change it. If you want a fixed outline not based on the point size (e.g. 3px), call `setScaledOutlineMode(False)` and `setOutlineThickness(3)`.

This class only supports single line, plain text strings with left/right/top/bottom/center alignment. If you want other QLabel features like hyperlinks, word wrap, elided text, etc. those will need to be implemented too. But chances are you wouldn’t use text outline in those cases anyway.

Here is an example to show that it will work for a variety of labels:

[image]

```
class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        label = OutlinedLabel('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit,')
        label.setStyleSheet('font-family: Monaco; font-size: 20pt')
        vbox.addWidget(label)

        label = OutlinedLabel('sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.')
        label.setStyleSheet('font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 30pt; font-weight: bold')
        vbox.addWidget(label)

        label = OutlinedLabel('Ut enim ad minim veniam,', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        label.setStyleSheet('font-family: Comic Sans MS; font-size: 40pt')
        vbox.addWidget(label)

        label = OutlinedLabel('quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut')
        label.setStyleSheet('font-family: Arial; font-size: 50pt; font-style: italic')
        vbox.addWidget(label)

        label = OutlinedLabel('aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.')
        label.setStyleSheet('font-family: American Typewriter; font-size: 60pt')
        label.setPen(Qt.red)
        vbox.addWidget(label)

        label = OutlinedLabel('Duis aute irure dolor', alignment=Qt.AlignRight)
        label.setStyleSheet('font-family: Luminari; font-size: 70pt')
        label.setPen(Qt.red); label.setBrush(Qt.black)
        vbox.addWidget(label)

        label = OutlinedLabel('in reprehenderit')
        label.setStyleSheet('font-family: Zapfino; font-size: 80pt')
        label.setBrush(Qt.red)
        vbox.addWidget(label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Template()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now Qt actually comes in clutch because you can get so much more out of this than just solid color text and outlines with all the QBrush/QPen options:

[image]

```
class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()                                          
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        text = 'Felicitations'
        
        label = OutlinedLabel(text)
        linearGrad = QLinearGradient(0, 1, 0, 0)
        linearGrad.setCoordinateMode(QGradient.ObjectBoundingMode)
        linearGrad.setColorAt(0, QColor('#0fd850'))
        linearGrad.setColorAt(1, QColor('#f9f047'))
        label.setBrush(linearGrad)
        label.setPen(Qt.darkGreen)
        vbox.addWidget(label)

        label = OutlinedLabel(text)
        radialGrad = QRadialGradient(0.3, 0.7, 0.05)
        radialGrad.setCoordinateMode(QGradient.ObjectBoundingMode)
        radialGrad.setSpread(QGradient.ReflectSpread)
        radialGrad.setColorAt(0, QColor('#0250c5'))
        radialGrad.setColorAt(1, QColor('#2575fc'))
        label.setBrush(radialGrad)
        label.setPen(QColor('Navy'))
        vbox.addWidget(label)
        
        label = OutlinedLabel(text)
        linearGrad.setStart(0, 0); linearGrad.setFinalStop(1, 0)
        linearGrad.setColorAt(0, Qt.cyan); linearGrad.setColorAt(1, Qt.magenta)
        label.setPen(QPen(linearGrad, 1)) # pen width is ignored
        vbox.addWidget(label)

        label = OutlinedLabel(text)
        linearGrad.setFinalStop(1, 1)
        for x in [(0, '#231557'), (0.29, '#44107A'), (0.67, '#FF1361'), (1, '#FFF800')]:
            linearGrad.setColorAt(x[0], QColor(x[1]))
        label.setBrush(linearGrad)
        label.setPen(QPen(QBrush(QColor('RoyalBlue'), Qt.Dense4Pattern), 1))
        label.setOutlineThickness(1 / 15)
        vbox.addWidget(label)

        label = OutlinedLabel(text)
        label.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.darkBlue, Qt.BDiagPattern))
        label.setPen(Qt.darkGray)
        vbox.addWidget(label)

        label = OutlinedLabel(text, styleSheet='background-color: black')
        label.setBrush(QPixmap('paint.jpg'))
        label.setPen(QColor('Lavender'))
        vbox.addWidget(label)
        
        self.setStyleSheet('''
        OutlinedLabel {
            font-family: Ubuntu;
            font-size: 60pt;
            font-weight: bold;
        }''')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Template()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that I’ve chosen to treat OutlinedLabel like a QGraphicsItem with the `setBrush`/`setPen` methods. If you want to use style sheets for the text color fill the path with `qp.fillPath(path, self.palette().text())`

Another option instead of calling `QPainter.strokePath` and then `QPainter.fillPath` is to generate a fillable outline of the text path with QPainterPathStroker, but I’ve noticed it’s slower. I would only use it to adjust the clarity of very small text by setting a larger width to the stroker than the pen. To try it replace the last 5 lines in `paintEvent` with:

```
qp.setBrush(self.brush)
self.pen.setWidthF(w)
qp.setPen(self.pen)
stroker = QPainterPathStroker()
stroker.setWidth(w)
qp.drawPath(stroker.createStroke(path).united(path))
```

Comment: Great example, thanks!! The example doesn't behave well when text contains newlines. how would you do it for multiple lines?

Comment: @laurapons You would need to call `QPainterPath.addText` for each line of text, with `path.addText(x, y, font, line)`, updating the XY values as you go along, e.g. incrementing the Y value by `metrics.height()` or index / number of lines.